# spring-integration-kafka: KafkaTemplate#setMessageConverter(RecordMessageConverter) has no effect

Tags: spring-integration, spring-kafka

I'm trying to set a custom message converter for my Spring Integration Kafka message handler (yes, I know I can supply serializer configs—I'm trying to do something a little different).

I have the following:

```
@Bean
public KafkaTemplate<String, String> kafkaTemplate() {
    final KafkaTemplate<String, String> kafkaTemplate = new KafkaTemplate<>(producerFactory());
    kafkaTemplate.setMessageConverter(new MessagingMessageConverter() {
        @Override
        public ProducerRecord<?, ?> fromMessage(final Message<?> message, final String s) {
            LOGGER.info("fromMessage({}, {})", message, s);
            return super.fromMessage(message, s);
        }
    });
    return kafkaTemplate;
}

@Bean
@ServiceActivator(inputChannel = "kafkaMessageChannel")
public MessageHandler kafkaMessageHandler() {
    final KafkaProducerMessageHandler<String, String> handler = new KafkaProducerMessageHandler<>(kafkaTemplate());
    handler.setTopicExpression(new LiteralExpression(getTopic()));
    handler.setSendSuccessChannel(kafkaSuccessChannel());
    return handler;
}
```

When a message is sent to `kafkaMessageChannel`, the handler sends it and the result shows up in `kafkaSuccessChannel`, but the `RecordMessageConverter` I set in the template was never called

Answer (score 0):

The template message converter is only used when using `template.send(Message<?>)` which is not used by the outbound channel adapter.

The outbound adapter maps the headers itself using its header mapper; there is no conversion performed on the message payload.

What documentation leads you to believe the converter is used in this context?

Comment: I think we need to add support of `ProducerRecord` in the `payload` of the request message. This way such a conversion could happen in advance before sending a message to this `KafkaProducerMessageHandler`.

Comment: I don't think it's quite that simple; some components of the producer record are built from the MessageHeaders e.g. key, partition. I think if someone wants to build their own `ProducerRecord` they should use a `KafkaTemplate` from a `@ServiceActivator` instead of using the outbound adapter.